# Set Session variable using Ajax

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, jquery

I have a popup form in which the user provide a key to get access to the page. Once the user provide the correct key I want to put the key in the session variable and as long as the session is active if the user refreshes the page the popup should not appear gain. What i have tried is

My JQuery

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#submit').click(function(e) {
        var key = $('#downloadkey').val();
        var box_id = $('#box_id').val();
        var dataString = {KEY:key, BID:box_id};
        $.ajax({
            url: "/mediabox/home/validate_key",
            type: 'POST',
            data: dataString,
            success: function(msg) {
                if(msg=="false"){
                   alert("Your download key is either wrong or you didn't provide it");
                }
                else{
                    $('#popupContact').hide();
                    $('#backgroundPopup').hide();
                }
            }
        });
    e.preventDefault();      
    });
});
</script>
```

My Home controller validate_key function

```
function validate_key(){
    $key = strtolower($this->input->post('KEY'));
    $id = $this->input->post('BID');
    $query = $this->db->get_where('mc_boxes', array('idmc_boxes' => $id));
    $row = $query->row();
    $download_key = strtolower($row->downloadkey);
    if($download_key == $key){
       $_SESSION['download_key'] = $key;
       $_SESSION['timeout'] = time();
    }
    else{
        echo 'false';
    }
}
```

In the validate_key function if the key provided by the user matches the one in database I set key in session variable.

The Script Where I load popup

```
if($download_key != null && !isset($_SESSION['download_key'])){?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){  
                loadPopup();    
            });  
        </script>
}
```

The loadpopup JS function is

```
 var popupStatus = 0; 
 //loading popup with jQuery magic!
 function loadPopup(){
 //loads popup only if it is disabled
   if(popupStatus==0){
      $("#backgroundPopup").css({
      "opacity": "0.7"
   });
   $("#backgroundPopup").fadeIn(1000);
   $("#popupContact").fadeIn(1000);
   popupStatus = 1;
 }
}
```

The problem is once I provide correct key and then I refresh the page it loads the popup again
How Can I prevent it from loading again and again after giving the right key?

Thanks in advance

Comment: are you calling `session_start()` anywhere ?

Comment: are you sure your $download_key always contains some value

Comment: yes I am sure it always contain a value

Comment: Thanks ManseUK I was calling session_start in a wrong place

Comment: could you explain the right place to put the session_start function for your example?